# Allow profile-pages to be viewed (By Everyone)

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know (if possible) how-to make a users profile page available to view by another user on a website. For Example an user has profile-page then another user can land on this page and view it and the contents.

At the moment I can associate the profile page with ONLY the user that it belongs to, Im not sure what step(s) to take next and in which order for another user to view. Below is a snippet of code I have that takes the user to their own profile the SESSION is unique to them therefore not letting any other user who is logged in to view the profile page.

I understand I may have to use a GET_REQUEST but have no idea how to put the id of the user that I'd like to be able to see as a GET variable

It would be great if somebody could point me in the right direction OR show me some example with code. I'm using MySQL and latest PHP.

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])){  // if session is true

// print to dash welcome + username 
            echo "Welcome to the website: ".$_SESSION['CurrentUser'];  

// append the user's name to the URL for profile page
            echo nl2br ("\n<a href=profile.php?id=".$_SESSION['CurrentUser'].">My Profile</a>"); /
        }
        else{
            echo ("not logged in");
        }
```

My `$_SESSION['CurrentUser']` is defined in my query-page that checks the username and password, `$_SESSION['CurrentUser'] = $_POST["username"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I use a user list in which each entry is linked to "profile.php?ref=**USER_ID**"

user_list

```
<?PHP
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result){ die('Ungültige Abfrage: ' . mysql_error()); }
    while ($output = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><?PHP if(!empty($output['user_avatar'])){ echo '<a href="./profile?req='.$output['user_id'].'"><img height="40px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $output['user_avatar'] ).'"/></a>'; } else { echo '<img height="40px" src="./style/img/avatar_default.jpg"/>'; }?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a href="./profile?req=<?PHP $output['user_id'] ?>"><?PHP echo $output['user_name'] ?></a></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?PHP echo $output['user_last_activity'] ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?PHP echo $output['user_register_date'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?
    }
?>
```

If you click on the username you got redirected to the profile page of the user (`profile.php?ref=$output['user_id']`)

If the profile.php is called I check if a **$_SESSION['user_id']** is set and the URL has no **req** parameter, if true I set **$req** with $_SESSION['user_id'] and otherwise i set **$req** with the req parameter from the URL **$_GET['req']**. Now I can submit the query with **$req** in the where clause

```
<?PHP
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($_GET['req'])){
        $req = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    } elseif(isset($_GET['req'])) {
        $req = $_GET['req'];
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$req."'");
    $user = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
?>
```

In conclusion the profile.php can be called with an parameter and without the req parameter.

I set the **$_SESSION['user_id']** during the login after the user validation.

Comment: Can you assist some more as Im still not sure what steps to take , Do I need to get the last inserted row of the ID when a users registers and then use that later as a GET REQUEST ?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I made it more detailed. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch for educating me, I have implemented the above demonstration and applied your answer,  now it works , Thanks .

Comment: @OvekShielder I help where I can, you can mark my answer as useful and right if you want. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Your correct so far in that only one user should own the rights to the page. But the site owner and admins have the right to view the page and also see a control panel that allows them suspend/ban or make someone a featured member.
 The site owner/admins would override this table with a master 'access_rights' table. Esentially they can see everything based on their rank / role. What your missing is a user level "view_status" table that has 'user_id' as a primary key to link it to existing tables. This table would have Boolean columns such as:
'is_public', 'is_private', 'is_family, 'is_friends, 'is_member, etc. This table grants only viewing rights-no more. You may need a sibling table to define *what* they can see on your page.
 Another table which would be a child of this one defines if a friend or member or family can post comments on your page, etc. PHP code does all of the cross-checking between tables to draw a final yes / no conclusion. These databases can get complex because human relations are complex.